# FParsec - parser sequences

Tags: parsing, f#, fparsec

Say I have some text:

```
a = "foobarbaz"
b = "foobar"
c = "foo"
d = "rubbish"
e = "foobazbar"
```

and three parsers foo, bar, and baz for the strings 'foo', 'bar' and 'baz' respectively.

How would I create a parser that would give me the results:

```
a = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
b = ["foo", "bar"]
c = ["foo"]
d = []
e = ["foo"]
```

when run against the inputs above? Basically attempt each possibility until failure whilst constructing a list. I could use user state but I would like to avoid if possible. (I would like to keep the individual parsers themselves ignorant of user state)

the closest I have gotten is something like fooseq below:

```
let foo = pstring "foo"
let bar = pstring "bar"
let baz = pstring "baz"

let foobar = pipe2 foo bar Seq.of2
let foobarbaz = pipe3 foo bar baz Seq.of3

let fooseq = choice (Seq.map attempt [foobarbaz; foobar; foo |>> Seq.of1 ;])

//(the Seq.ofx functions just take arguments and create a sequence of them)
```

It seems to me there must be a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FParsec has no built-in sequence combinator that does exactly what you're looking for, but you could implement one yourself like in the following example:

```
let mySeq (parsers: seq<Parser<'t,'u>>) : Parser<'t[],'u> =
  let ps = Array.ofSeq parsers
  if ps.Length = 0 then preturn [||]
  else
    fun stream ->   
      let mutable stateTag = stream.StateTag
      let mutable reply = ps.[0] stream
      let mutable error = reply.Error
      let mutable myReply = Reply()
      if reply.Status <> Ok then myReply.Result <- [||]
      else
        // create array to hold results
        let mutable xs = Array.zeroCreate ps.Length
        xs.[0] <- reply.Result
        let mutable i = 1
        while i < ps.Length do                    
          stateTag <- stream.StateTag
          reply <- ps.[i] stream
          error <- if stateTag <> stream.StateTag then reply.Error
                   else mergeErrors error reply.Error
          if reply.Status = Ok then
            xs.[i] <- reply.Result
            i <- i + 1
          else // truncate array and break loop         
            xs <- Array.sub xs 0 i
            i <- ps.Length 
        myReply.Result <- xs
      myReply.Status <- if reply.Status = Error && stateTag = stream.StateTag 
                        then Ok
                        else reply.Status
      myReply.Error <- error            
      myReply
```

With the `mySeq` combinator, you can express your `fooSeq` parser as

```
let fooSeq = mySeq [foo; bar; baz]
```